# WindowsForms TextBox Method Paste also in WPF TextBox?

Tags: wpf, winforms, text, textbox

In WindowsForms i use this samlpe code:

```
textBox.Paste("some text");
```

Is there a TextBox method with the same function in WPF?
Or there is a nice workaround?

Comment: Maby this workaround to use the Textox in WPF helps: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/using-windows-forms-controls-in-wpf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public static void Paste(this TextBox textbox, string textToInsert)
    {
        int caretIndex = textbox.CaretIndex;
        string textBoxContent;

        if (textbox.SelectedText.Length > 0)
        {
            textBoxContent = textbox.Text.Remove(caretIndex, textbox.SelectedText.Length);
        }
        else
        {
            textBoxContent = textbox.Text;
        }

        textbox.Text = textBoxContent.Insert(caretIndex, textToInsert);
        textbox.CaretIndex = caretIndex + textToInsert.Length;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Clipboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.clipboard.aspx) class:

```
textBox1.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
```

or use the [SelectedText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectedtext.aspx) property of the textbox:

```
textBox1.SelectedText = "some text";
```

Comment: Probably this is not the same, since [`Paste`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160635.aspx) does replace the currently selected text, whereas your solution will replace all text.

Comment: Additionally, you use the clipboard whereas the original poster does not use the clipboard.